# How to calculate time difference between two difference values continously in pandas using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time

Here I have a dataset with three inputs x1,x2,x3 with date and time. Here in my X3 column I have similar values in rows.

What I want to do is I want to find the time difference in similar values in rows  when the start time will be 0.

Here I used the code , but it gave me time difference from other columns also.
here is my code:

```
df['time_diff']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + " " + df['time'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', dayfirst=True)
df['Duration'] = df.groupby('x3')['time_diff'].diff()
```

Gave me this time difference , But it is not the solution what I look

[image]

But my expected output is:

```html
date time                 x3         Expected output of time difference
10/3/2018 6:00:00         0          NaN
10/3/2018 7:00:00         5          0 =start time for 5
10/3/2018 8:00:00         0          NaN
10/3/2018 9:00:00         7          0=start time for 7
10/3/2018 10:00:00 0          NaN
10/3/2018 11:00:00 0          NaN
10/3/2018 12:00:00 0          NaN
10/3/2018 13:45:00 0          NaN
10/3/2018 15:00:00 0          NaN
10/3/2018 16:00:00 0          NaN
10/3/2018 17:00:00 0          NaN
10/3/2018 18:00:00 0          NaN
10/3/2018 19:00:00 5          12 hr =from starting time of 5
10/3/2018 20:00:00 0          NaN
10/3/2018 21:30:00 7          12.30hr = from starting time of 7
10/4/2018 6:00:00         0         NaN
10/4/2018 7:00:00         0         NaN
10/4/2018 8:00:00         5         0 = starting time of 5 because new day
10/4/2018 9:00:00         7         0 = starting time of 5 because new day
10/4/2018 11:00:00 5         3hr
10/4/2018 12:00:00 5         4hr
10/4/2018 13:00:00 5         5hr
10/4/2018 16:00:00 0         NaN
10/4/2018 17:00:00 0         NaN
10/4/2018 18:00:00 7         11hr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter out rows with `x3==0` and `groupby` with both columns with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) for reepat first value per all values of group, so possible subtract by original column with converting to hours:

```
df['time_diff']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + " " + df['time'],
                                format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', dayfirst=True)

mask = df['x3'].ne(0)
df['Duration'] = df[mask].groupby(['date','x3'])['time_diff'].transform('first')
df['Duration'] = df['time_diff'].sub(df['Duration']).dt.total_seconds().div(3600)
print (df)
         date      time  x3 Expected           time_diff  Duration
0   10/3/2018   6:00:00   0      NaN 2018-03-10 06:00:00       NaN
1   10/3/2018   7:00:00   5        0 2018-03-10 07:00:00       0.0
2   10/3/2018   8:00:00   0      NaN 2018-03-10 08:00:00       NaN
3   10/3/2018   9:00:00   7        0 2018-03-10 09:00:00       0.0
4   10/3/2018  10:00:00   0      NaN 2018-03-10 10:00:00       NaN
5   10/3/2018  11:00:00   0      NaN 2018-03-10 11:00:00       NaN
6   10/3/2018  12:00:00   0      NaN 2018-03-10 12:00:00       NaN
7   10/3/2018  13:45:00   0      NaN 2018-03-10 13:45:00       NaN
8   10/3/2018  15:00:00   0      NaN 2018-03-10 15:00:00       NaN
9   10/3/2018  16:00:00   0      NaN 2018-03-10 16:00:00       NaN
10  10/3/2018  17:00:00   0      NaN 2018-03-10 17:00:00       NaN
11  10/3/2018  18:00:00   0      NaN 2018-03-10 18:00:00       NaN
12  10/3/2018  19:00:00   5     12hr 2018-03-10 19:00:00      12.0
13  10/3/2018  20:00:00   0      NaN 2018-03-10 20:00:00       NaN
14  10/3/2018  21:30:00   7  12.30hr 2018-03-10 21:30:00      12.5
15  10/4/2018   6:00:00   0      NaN 2018-04-10 06:00:00       NaN
16  10/4/2018   7:00:00   0      NaN 2018-04-10 07:00:00       NaN
17  10/4/2018   8:00:00   5        0 2018-04-10 08:00:00       0.0
18  10/4/2018   9:00:00   7        0 2018-04-10 09:00:00       0.0
19  10/4/2018  11:00:00   5      3hr 2018-04-10 11:00:00       3.0
20  10/4/2018  12:00:00   5      4hr 2018-04-10 12:00:00       4.0
21  10/4/2018  13:00:00   5      5hr 2018-04-10 13:00:00       5.0
22  10/4/2018  16:00:00   0      NaN 2018-04-10 16:00:00       NaN
23  10/4/2018  17:00:00   0      NaN 2018-04-10 17:00:00       NaN
24  10/4/2018  18:00:00   7     11hr 2018-04-10 18:00:00       9.0
```

Comment: Hay thank you for the fast reply. It works for me. You saved my day thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

```
mask = df['x3'].ne(0)
df['Duration'] = df[mask].groupby(['date','x3'])['time_diff'].apply(lambda x : (((x-x.iloc[0])//timedelta(minutes=1))/60))
```

**Output**

```
date         time      x3   time_diff            Duration
10/3/2018   6:00:00     0   2018-03-10 06:00:00     NaN
10/3/2018   7:00:00     5   2018-03-10 07:00:00     0.0
10/3/2018   8:00:00     0   2018-03-10 08:00:00     NaN
10/3/2018   9:00:00     7   2018-03-10 09:00:00     0.0
10/3/2018   10:00:00    0   2018-03-10 10:00:00     NaN
10/3/2018   11:00:00    0   2018-03-10 11:00:00     NaN
10/3/2018   12:00:00    0   2018-03-10 12:00:00     NaN
10/3/2018   13:45:00    0   2018-03-10 13:45:00     NaN
10/3/2018   15:00:00    0   2018-03-10 15:00:00     NaN
10/3/2018   16:00:00    0   2018-03-10 16:00:00     NaN
10/3/2018   17:00:00    0   2018-03-10 17:00:00     NaN
10/3/2018   18:00:00    0   2018-03-10 18:00:00     NaN
10/3/2018   19:00:00    5   2018-03-10 19:00:00     12.0
10/3/2018   20:00:00    0   2018-03-10 20:00:00     NaN
10/3/2018   21:30:00    7   2018-03-10 21:30:00     12.5
10/4/2018   6:00:00     0   2018-04-10 06:00:00     NaN
10/4/2018   7:00:00     0   2018-04-10 07:00:00     NaN
10/4/2018   8:00:00     5   2018-04-10 08:00:00     0.0
10/4/2018   9:00:00     7   2018-04-10 09:00:00     0.0
10/4/2018   11:00:00    5   2018-04-10 11:00:00     3.0
10/4/2018   12:00:00    5   2018-04-10 12:00:00     4.0
10/4/2018   13:00:00    5   2018-04-10 13:00:00     5.0
10/4/2018   16:00:00    0   2018-04-10 16:00:00     NaN
10/4/2018   17:00:00    0   2018-04-10 17:00:00     NaN
10/4/2018   18:00:00    7   2018-04-10 18:00:00     9.0
```

Comment: There is an error "name 'timedelta' is not defined"

Comment: Add this to the code `from datetime import timedelta`